# How to review different recipe revisions of the same package version?

Tags: conan

Previously I used for that conan center website.
But for now it shows only latest recipe revision. Is there any api or command to view all revisions?
My conan versios is less than 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the command `conan search` can be used for that:

```
conan search zlib/1.2.13@ --revisions -r=conancenter
Revisions for 'zlib/1.2.13' at remote 'conancenter':
97d5730b529b4224045fe7090592d4c1 (2023-08-22 02:51:57 UTC)
e377bee636333ae348d51ca90874e353 (2023-04-27 12:11:24 UTC)
13c96f538b52e1600c40b88994de240f (2022-11-02 13:46:53 UTC)
647c91ed13c0a6c9ea9add6ca968ea93 (2022-10-19 09:19:10 UTC)
40e9a7e11e440715c0f0f3e96448342b (2022-10-14 12:06:41 UTC)
```

It needs revisions enabled. It also has the `--json=myfile.json` argument to create a json file with the results